# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake httpclient4.5.2 + java8

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Google Contacts API to get the contacts from Google. For that, i need access_token from Google.
To get the access_token I'm making the request like below :

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

```
    try {
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(googleTokenUrl);
        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", googleClientId));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", googleClientSecret));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", webUrl + googleRedirectUri));

        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Consts.UTF_8));
        CloseableHttpResponse closeableresponse = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        logger.debug("Response Status line :" + closeableresponse.getStatusLine());

        try {
            HttpEntity entity = closeableresponse.getEntity();
            InputStream rstream = entity.getContent();
            JSONObject authResponse = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(rstream));
            String access_token = authResponse.getString("access_token");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            logger.error(" Exception occured :  " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } finally {
            closeableresponse.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error(" Exception occured :  " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            httpclient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(" Exception occured :  " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

but it is throwing error like "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake".

I'm using httpclient4.5.2 + java8 + apache tomcat8+ eclipse

Comment: copying Iron's answer, as it should be a comment and will likely get removed - in order to see the exception correctly, you have to log it like this, logger.error(" Exception occured : " , ex); and you will see the stacktrace. Copy and paste the detailed result

Comment: Have you registered with the Google API Console?

Comment: yes i registered-AgentBawls.